# Trouble with forEach

Tags: javascript

I have this array:

```
items = []
items[0] = {id: "805", category: 'Apple'}
items[1] = {id: "804", category: 'Watermelon'}
items[2] = {id: "804", category: 'Plum'}
```

And the forEach, when i get the `category value`.

```
var result = '';
items.forEach(function(item) {
result += item.category;
});
console.log(result);
```

But the problem is that in the console.log I get `Apple, Watermelon, Plum`, which var result giving me. How i can get input like this in console -

```
Apple
Watermelon
Plum
```

Comment: The items in question have no such property `descr`.

Comment: `item.descr` to `item.category`

Comment: `items.forEach(item => console.log(item.category))`

Comment: how is the function suppose to know what `.descr` is? It's not even a key in the original array.

Comment: Your array sample, your code and the described result all do not correspond in any way.

Comment: I suggest if you found any of the answers useful clicking the up arrows next to them to give the answerer (who volunteered their time to help you) points, especially the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to do:

```js
items = []
items[0] = {id: "805", category: 'Apple'}
items[1] = {id: "804", category: 'Watermelon'}
items[2] = {id: "804", category: 'Plum'}


items.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item.category);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add newlines:

```js
const items = [
  {id: "805", category: 'Apple'},
  {id: "804", category: 'Watermelon'},
  {id: "804", category: 'Plum'}
];

let result = '';
items.forEach(function(item) {
  if (result) result += '\n';
  result += item.category;
});
console.log(result);
```

But when iterating over an array to produce a single value at the end, it's more appropriate to use `.reduce`:

```js
const items = [
  {id: "805", category: 'Apple'},
  {id: "804", category: 'Watermelon'},
  {id: "804", category: 'Plum'}
];

const result = items.reduce((resultSoFar, item) => {
  if (resultSoFar) resultSoFar += '\n';
  resultSoFar += item.category;
  return resultSoFar;
}, '');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `'\n'` at the end

```js
items = []
items[0] = {id: "805", category: 'Apple'}
items[1] = {id: "804", category: 'Watermelon'}
items[2] = {id: "804", category: 'Plum'}

var result = '';
items.forEach(function(item) {
  result += item.category+'\n';  //add '\n' at the end
});

result=result.substr(0,result.length-1);  // remove last character(which is '\n')
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    items = []
    items[0] = {id: "805", category: 'Apple'}
    items[1] = {id: "804", category: 'Watermelon'}
    items[2] = {id: "804", category: 'Plum'}

    var result = '';
    items.forEach(function(item)
    {
      result += item.category + '\r\n';
    });
    
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

In your case you would use a combination of `map` and `join`. `map` creats an array that just contains the the values of `category`, and `join` will join those values together.

```js
items = [
   {id: "805", category: 'Apple'},
   {id: "804", category: 'Watermelon'},
   {id: "804", category: 'Plum'}
]

var result =  items.map(item => item.category).join('\n')
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    items = []
    items[0] = {id: "805", category: 'Apple'}
    items[1] = {id: "804", category: 'Watermelon'}
    items[2] = {id: "804", category: 'Plum'}


    var result = '';
    items.forEach(function(item) {
        result += item.category;
    });
   console.log(result);
```

Use above code. Error was with dscr attribute